# Barcode scanning SDK for iOS 7?

Tags: ios, barcode

Is their any barcode scanning SDK available for iOS 7 by which I can parse the information of barcode ?

Comment: Have you tried [Z-Bar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/install.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also go for scandit please find the below link for the same
http://www.scandit.com/barcode-scanner-sdk/features/platforms/

Answer (score 2):

I think ZBar is iOS7 compatible:

http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/index.html

Comment: but it is described on the docs that it will work only with iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4

Comment: I'm using ZBar, and it does seem to work with newer models too.